# Convert the following switch statement into if-else statements:

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, switch-statement

```java
int month = input.nextInt();
switch (month) { 
    case 1:
        System.out.println(“January”);
    case 2:
        System.out.println(“February”); break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(“March”); break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println(“April”);
    case 5:
        System.out.println(“May”); break;
    default:
        System.out.println(“Invalid”); break;
}
```

How do I convert it from `switch` statement into `if`-`else` statment?

the breaks are intentional, this is a college assignment.

Comment: Handle every `case` with an `if` or `else if`... `default` means `else`.

Comment: First of all, you choose a language - javascript is not java (your code is in Java, in case you are not sure). I removed the javascript tag, but you can edit if that is not what you wanted (but make sure to explain why).

Comment: why are some `break` statements missing? is it intentionally?

Comment: Also, please explain what exactly is unclear about this - have you already tried something?

Comment: @NinaScholz Probably some traps set by his teacher/professor in his homework/assignment.

Comment: its for a class assignment, im new to java and im not sure what to do when in comes to the break statements. they are intentional and part of the question my professor gave.

Comment: please add your try. what does not work?

Comment: Please focus on the specific problem you encountered while trying yourself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code, you could check all connected parts, without a `break` statement, together in a single statement and check the values in another nested `if` statement.

```
if 1 or 2
    if 1 print january
    print february
else if 3 print march
else if 4 or 5 
    if 4 print april
    print may
else print invalid
```

Comment: Nice answer to a homework question, helping with the core problem without just providing teacher-acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int month = input.nextInt();
if(month==1){
    System.out.println(“January”);
    System.out.println(“February”);
}else if(month==2){
    System.out.println(“February”);
}
```

you should be able to repeat that for the next cases. Please try to clean up your code next time, if we are giving time to answer you should at least put in time to ask properly, thanks

Comment: according to the OP's code, the month of `1` should also print `February`

Comment: oh ya I forgot to forget about that just add a `System.out.println("February");` under the January one and your good to go

Comment: That would introduce copies of code, which I guess will not satisfy the teacher.